# How to filter by `describe` and `it`?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

For example, I to have

```
describe('element', () => {
  desctibe('button', () => {
    it('default', () => {
      // ...
    });

    it('other', () => {
      // ...
    });
  });

  describe('checkbox', () => {
    it('default', () => {
      // ...
    });

    it('other', () => {
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

If I try to filter by a test name regex pattern «def», then I'll get:

```
Pattern matches 2 tests from cached test suites
 › default
 › default
```

From result not understandable, what is what, but  I would like this:

```
Pattern matches 2 tests from cached test suites
 › element button default
 › element checkbox default
```

That is, I want to not just see `describe` but also filter by `describe` and `it`.

But how?

Comment: You do not want to use regular expressions on source code. Think about a different approach.

Comment: Do not understand. My question is: "How to filter by `describe` or/and `it`?"